# Draggable/tabbable UIPopOverController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, view

I don't know if you people are familiar with the Blackboard Learn app for iPad. Well it has PopUp windows to show info.

Well, I would like to implement something similar on a iPad app, and I was wondering if it is possible to doit with UIPopOverControllers...

Basically you can open a view and drag it around and keep it on a border of the screen as a tab to show updates and so.

Is it possible to do something similar with UIPopOverControllers or UIViews (the dragging and the tabbing)?

Cheers from Mexico

---

UPDATE 1:

Well, I managed to load multiple UIViews, next thing goes to be able to drag 'em around, any suggestions?

---

UPDATE 2:

I tried to add the UIPanGestureRecognizer in otherView.m (the Pop Up Window), here's how it looks

otherView.h

```
@interface otherView : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *drag;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPanGestureRecognizer *drag;

...
```

otherView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Drag
    drag = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragAction)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:drag];
    [drag release];
}
```

otherView is displayed in mainWindow directly from the appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch.

    // Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window addSubview:secondView.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Hope you can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no mechanism to move a popover around on the screen - they are attached to a bar button or point in a view and that is where they exist until they are dismissed. Popovers also don't allow interaction with views (buttons, text fields etc) in the main view while they are visible.

Sounds like a great user interface concept though, good luck!!

Comment: Then I guess I could load a UIView instead, but I'm not sure if that is possible (open a smaller UIView when button is pressed while the main view is still visible in the background).

Comment: Well, I managed to load multiple UIViews, next thing goes to be able to drag 'em around, any suggestions?

Comment: create a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for the UIView you want to move around. Be careful measure the position relative to the view's parent, otherwise moving the view could confuse the gesture.

Comment: Where should I declare the UIPanGestureRecognizer? In the Delegate, the main window or the smaller one (The one that shows as a popout and is the one that is draggable). In the Update 2 there's what I've tried

Comment: I don't think it matters where you declare it, but you attach it to the view that you want to move with: `[theMovingView addGestureRecognizer: myPanGesture];` and assign a target and selector on the gesture to something like this: `[myPanGesture addTarget:myMainViewController action:@selector(doSomethingWithPanGesture:)];` and you method would be defined in your view controller class as  `- (void)doSomethingWithPanGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {}` Gestures are pretty nice to work with - have fun!!